# creating a balanced gray code with digits of different parity

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have some code that generates all combinations from something like this:

```
[the or a] and [angry or mad or furious] and [cat or feline]
```

to this:

```
the angry cat
the mad cat
the furious cat
the angry feline
the mad feline
the furious feline
a angry cat
a mad cat
a furious cat
a angry feline
a mad feline
a furious feline
```

The problem is that this cross product may become too large, in which case I would like to fairly sample as many combinations as possible in a given time limit.  This is very similar to balanced gray codes but the parity is not the same for each "digit".

The obvious algorithms (e.g. Breadth-First search and Depth-First search) will oversample some combinations and completely ignore others which probabilistic sampling like monte-carlo will evenly sample all combinations very well but it cannot efficiently enumerate all combinations.  Does anyone know of any algorithm for solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have $n_i$ options for slot $i$. Find the total number $n=\prod_in_i$ of possibilities, and find the next higher prime $p$. Find a [primitive root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) $a$ modulo $p$, and traverse its powers $a^k$ modulo $p$. Skip the very few cases where the residue is greater than $n$. In all other cases, subtract $1$, successively divide by the $n_i$ and use the remainders as indices for the options.

In your example $n=12$, $p=13$, and e.g. $6$ is a primitive root modulo $13$. Its powers are $6$, $10$, $8$, $9$, $2$, $12$, $7$, $3$, $5$, $4$, $11$, $1$. If we subtract $1$, then divide by $2$ and use the remainder to index $\{\text{the},\text{a}\}$, then divide by $3$ and use the remainder to index $\{\text{angry},\text{mad},\text{furious}\}$, and then use what's left to index $\{\text{cat},\text{feline}\}$, this yields the following enumeration:

```
a furious cat
a mad feline
a angry feline
the mad feline
a angry cat
a furious feline
the angry feline
the mad cat
the furious cat
a mad cat
the furious feline
the angry cat
```

Comment: Do you know if there are any libraries that implement this in some programming language?

Comment: @anthonybell: I don't. I could write you a Java class that does it.

Comment: ok, thanks.  I was just curious because I couldn't find anything earlier.  Do you know if there are any kind of theoretical guarantees of randomness that can be said about enumerations generated with this method?

Comment: @anthonybell: I don't, I made it up on the spot.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a very similar approach to the [answer by @joriki](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1818586/59314), which is in may ways simpler to implement (it requires neither primes nor the discovery of primitive roots), and which has been analyzed extensively:

As above, find $n=\prod_in_i$ and then find $m=2^{\lceil{log_2 n}\rceil}$. Finally, generate a random $a$ and $c$ such that $0<a,c<m, a\equiv1\pmod 4, c\equiv1\pmod2$. Then use a [Linear Congruential Generator (LCG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) starting with some randomly-selected $x_0$, producing at each step $x_{i+1} = a x_i + c\pmod m$. Skip over any values of $x_i$ which are greater than or equal to $m$ (which will be fewer than half the generated values) and converted the remaining ones to option sequences using a mixed-base representation.

The LCG produced in this way is guaranteed to cycle through all $m$ values, and for particular values of $a$ and $c$ could be used as a cheap pseudo-random number generator. It's performance as such has been analysed extensively. Not all values of $a$ are equally good; in general, you should use values somewhere in the vicinity of $\sqrt m$. One weakness of an LCG is that the low-order bits of successive entries are highly correlated. However, that will not bias the composition of a sample.